# zsh compinit errors

Tags: terminal, permission, zsh

I have errors with the zsh shell:

> zsh compinit: insecure directories and files, run compaudit for list

the files listed with errors are

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
```

People suggest to change the ownership of these to the user having the problem.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /usr/local/share/zsh`

But I have multiple users in my mac so this doesn't make sense. Beside /usr/local stuff should be run by any user AFAIK.

Further to this the user with the problem is not in the sudoers list, so if I run the above command with the admin user won't fix it.

Permissions currently look like this

`drwxr-xr-x  8 userwithAdmin  staff  256 19 Nov 15:18 site-functions`

the user with the problem is not userwithAdmin but userB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who was the original owner - zsh manual https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html says it should be root or current owner - so with multiple users it must be root

Comment: @mmmmmm I've no idea who the original owner was, I've changed it to root but the problem remains.

Comment: By any chance are you running homebrew?

Comment: @mmmmmm yes this is probably homebrew related.

Comment: Homebre messes up Unix permissions by making /usr/local writable by a user. So choose homebrew or zsh compinit. Homebrew is designed as if there is one user on the machine. If you have multiple then use another package manager eg macports or fink that are designed as normal unix usage and so require sudo to install

Comment: @mmmmmm so you're saying if change ownership of /usr/local to root staff the error would go away but would break brew?

Comment: I think so - however I can't test as I don't use Homebrew

Comment: Actually /usr/local should be root:wheel  - wheel is the group for admin users

Comment: for some reason I can't do it operation not permitted even with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mmmmmm suggested this is related to brew installation.

Actually I applied the suggestion by @Alf Eaton here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories

```
chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share"
```

and it solved the problem. I can't explain  but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed zsh-completions, and ran this as per the notes:

Additionally, if you receive "zsh compinit: insecure directories" warnings when attempting
to load these completions, you may need to run these commands:

> ```
>   chmod go-w '/usr/local/share'
>   chmod -R go-w '/usr/local/share/zsh'
> ```